# Angular 8 sobre App Engine app.yaml

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

Estoy intentando desplegar una app sencilla Angular 8 sobre App Engine.
Anterior mente lo hice con Angular 6 y este el es app.yaml que si funciona para esa versión:

```html
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true



skip_files:
- ^(node_modules/.*)
- ^(.git/.*)
- ^(env/.*)
- ^(.*/)?.*\.pyc$
- .vscode/


handlers:



# Routing for bundles to serve directly
- url: /((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|runtime|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/((?:inline|main|polyfills|styles|runtime|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js)
  application_readable: true


# Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
- url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.css)


# Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
- url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)



#Routing for typedoc, assets and favicon.ico to serve directly
- url: /index.html
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  application_readable: true


- url: /api/task/.*
  script: modules.task.app
  secure: always

  
- url: /api/.*
  script: backend.app
  secure: always

# - url: /api/report/.*
#   script: modules.reports.app
#   secure: always

- url: /(.*)
  script: backend.app
  secure: always


libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest
- name: lxml
  version: "3.7.3"
```

Creo que la compilación en dist ha cambiado respecto a la versión 6 de Angular. Ahora la estructura es la siguiente:

```html
.
├── 3rdpartylicenses.txt
├── assets
│   └── images
│       ├── altostratus.png
│       └── summit.png
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── main-es2015.c6bccfc48623da989f20.js
├── main-es5.19b3b8b4157f53ceb7d7.js
├── polyfills-es2015.e954256595c973372414.js
├── polyfills-es5.405730e5ac8f727bd7d7.js
├── runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js
├── runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js
└── styles.a4322bb3420f641d6cc5.css
```

A la hora de ver localhost:8080 recibo:

> http://localhost:8080/main-es2015.c6bccfc48623da989f20.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

No termino de entender como funciona el app.yaml y sus expresiones regulares. Alguien me ilumina?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS corre del lado del cliente, por lo que para App Engine esto será contenido estático.

Ya que es contenido estático de acuerdo a la [documentación de Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) es necesario incluir el handler de archivos estáticos.

Te dejo aquí los handlers de archivos estáticos.

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```